# how to get unique sum difference in a group

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm trying to solve below problem

```
CREATE TABLE names( id INT primary key, place VARCHAR2(15), opinion VARCHAR2(2));

/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO names VALUES (1, 'mount', 'r');
INSERT INTO names VALUES (2, 'mount', 'nr');
INSERT INTO names VALUES (3, 'cod', 'r');
INSERT INTO names VALUES (4, 'cod', 'r');
INSERT INTO names VALUES (5, 'cod', 'r');
INSERT INTO names VALUES (6, 'qr', 'r');
INSERT INTO names VALUES (7, 'qr', 'nr');
INSERT INTO names VALUES (8, 'cafe', 'nr');
INSERT INTO names VALUES (9, 'mount', 'r');
```

want to get places in output, whose respective count `(r - nr)` is `greater than or equal to one`.

- If only `r` is present for a specific place, then we should that
  place in output.
- If only `nr` is present for a specific place, then we `should not`
  that place in output
- If both are present, then consider place whose (r-nr) >=1

not able to think after this

```sql
SELECT place, opinion, COUNT(*) as cnt
  FROM names
 GROUP BY place, opinion;
```

output names

```
mount
cod
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is using `SIGN(SUM(DECODE()))` combination along  with `HAVING` clause while grouping by `place` column   such as

```sql
SELECT place
  FROM names
 GROUP BY place
HAVING SIGN( SUM( DECODE(opinion,'r',1,'nr',-1) ) ) = 1
```

where

- `DECODE()` seperates the cases as numerical values
- `SUM()` determines total occurence difference
- `SIGN()` determines whether each difference is a positive integer or not

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9ff4bf30e2e11b9a72cd87138b18e25b)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Using a conditional aggregation

```
select place
from names
group by place
having sum(case opinion when 'r' then 1 when 'nr' then -1 end) >= 1
```